# What are mvc checkbox filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want the brands to pop out whenever a specific brand gets selected. For example, whenever I select adidas, I want adidas products to show up on the website.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAKbO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Write onChange function of Checkbox in javascript and post checkbox value to your controller to filter data based on selected value